# Should we allow questions that are quite possibly very limited in time-scope?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

... I'm thinking of questions like "what supplements for Game *X* are in print?", or "who's the current publisher of Game *Y*?".

It seems to me that there are two ways to go: allow these questions but require/hope that they be kept up to date so that they record information as it develops through time; or, close them as too time-limited in scope and not useful over the long term.

Comment: Unless there's a lot of productive discussion around this, and perhaps even then, I'm loathe to accept any particular answer as "the right one" myself...

Answer (score 8):

In general these are too localized, and in terms of "what supplements are in print" is worse, a list question. Saying they'll be edited and kept up to date is wishful thinking.

Comment: Although looking at the "in print" question it's actually a little different, it's asking which already released products are print vs PDF only which is a more useful question to my mind. As opposed to "what has been released" which is an everchanging list.

Comment: But the PDF versus Print distinction, although useful, could also change over time and is something that could (easily) be checked by looking at the publisher's website, or checking with the game PDF vendors? I get that stacks's philosophy is "be a one-stop-shop for answers", but isn't it better to support questions that are not easily answered by the publishers/vendors themselves?

Comment: Anything can change over time, man. And the guy already checked the vendor page and rpggeek and it wasn't clear, apparently.  In any event, close as dumbass question is different from close as too narrow.

Answer (score 5):

That sort of constantly-changing information seems best suited to a venue like Wikipedia. For example, see the [production history for Shadowrun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowrun#Production_history), and the [history of Earthdawn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthdawn#History). I'm not suggesting that in all cases Wikipedia can tell you whether a product is in print or not, but it seems like a more appropriate place for that information to live.

Answer (score -1):

Since answers are ultimately editable if you saw an answer that had fallen out of date couldn't you go in and edit it with the relevant information?  The who is the current publisher might not be as good of a question but you could update an answer by stating "up until X/X/XX Publisher Q handled Game Y but now Publisher Z handles it."

I think it'd be to our benefit if people knew we had a dynamic community willing to keep track of such information.